# DEBUG: Crawled (404)

Tags: python, scrapy

This is my code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy


class SinasharesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'SinaShares'
    allowed_domains = ['money.finance.sina.com.cn/mkt/']
    start_urls = ['http://money.finance.sina.com.cn/mkt//']

    def parse(self, response):
        contents=response.xpath('//*[@id="list_amount_ctrl"]/a[2]/@class').extract()
        print(contents)
```

And I have set an user-agent in setting.py.

Then I get an error:

```
2020-04-27 10:54:50 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (404) <GET http://money.finance.sina.com.cn/robots.txt> (referer: None)
2020-04-27 10:54:50 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://money.finance.sina.com.cn/mkt//> (referer: None)
```

So How can I eliminate this error?

Comment: These are just debugging messages that tell you what happened when scrapy tried to access those URLs. Not error messages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The http-statuscode **404** is received because Scrapy is checking the /robots.txt by default. In your case this site does not exist and so a 404 is received but that does not have any impact. In case you want to avoid checking the robots.txt you can set ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = False in the settings.py.

Then the website is accessed successfully (http-statuscode **200**). No content is printed because based on your xpath-selection nothing is selected. You have to fix your xpath-selection.

If you want to test different xpath- or css-selections in order to figure how to get your desired content, you might want to use the interactive scrapy shell:
`scrapy shell "http://money.finance.sina.com.cn/mkt/"`

You can find an example of a scrapy shell session in [the official Scrapy documentation here](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/shell.html#example-of-shell-session).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your ip is banned by the website,also you can need to add some cookies to crawling the data that you needed.