# DEBUG: Crawled (404) when crawling table with Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I am quite new to `Scrapy` and I try to get table data from every page from this [website](https://www.uaeonlinedirectory.com/UFZOnlineDirectory.aspx?item=A).

[image]

But first, I just want to get the table data from `page 1`.

This is my code:

```
import scrapy

class UAESpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'uae_free'

    allowed_domains = ['https://www.uaeonlinedirectory.com']

    start_urls = [
        'https://www.uaeonlinedirectory.com/UFZOnlineDirectory.aspx?item=A'
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        zones = response.xpath('//table[@class="GridViewStyle"]/tbody/tr')
        for zone in zones[1:]:
            yield {
                'company_name': zone.xpath('.//td[1]//text()').get(),
                'zone': zone.xpath('.//td[2]//text()').get(),
                'category': zone.xpath('.//td[4]//text()').get()
            }
```

On the terminal, I get this message:

```
2020-07-01 08:41:07 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2020-07-01 08:41:07 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2020-07-01 08:41:07 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2020-07-01 08:41:09 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (404) <GET https://www.uaeonlinedirectory.com/robots.txt> (referer: None)
2020-07-01 08:41:09 [protego] DEBUG: Rule at line 1 without any user agent to enforce it on.
2020-07-01 08:41:09 [protego] DEBUG: Rule at line 2 without any user agent to enforce it on.
2020-07-01 08:41:09 [protego] DEBUG: Rule at line 8 without any user agent to enforce it on.
2020-07-01 08:41:09 [protego] DEBUG: Rule at line 9 without any user agent to enforce it on.
2020-07-01 08:41:09 [protego] DEBUG: Rule at line 10 without any user agent to enforce it on.
2020-07-01 08:41:09 [protego] DEBUG: Rule at line 11 without any user agent to enforce it on.
2020-07-01 08:41:09 [protego] DEBUG: Rule at line 12 without any user agent to enforce it on.
2020-07-01 08:41:14 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.uaeonlinedirectory.com/UFZOnlineDirectory.aspx?item=A> (referer: None)
2020-07-01 08:41:14 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
```

Do you guys know what is this message about and what wrong with my code?

**Update:**

I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61453874/9500955), and after I set `ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = False`, I don't receive the message above anymore. But I still cannot get the data.

The terminal message after I set `ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = False`:

```
2020-07-01 08:56:03 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2020-07-01 08:56:03 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2020-07-01 08:56:03 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2020-07-01 08:56:07 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.uaeonlinedirectory.com/UFZOnlineDirectory.aspx?item=A> (referer: None)
2020-07-01 08:56:07 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
```

**Update 2:**

I open terminal and use `scrapy shell https://www.uaeonlinedirectory.com/UFZOnlineDirectory.aspx?item=A` to check my xpath:

```
>>> response.xpath('//table[@class="GridViewStyle"]')
[<Selector xpath='//table[@class="GridViewStyle"]' data='<table class="GridViewStyle" cellspac...'>]
>>> response.xpath('//table[@class="GridViewStyle"]/tbody')
[]
```

So does my xpath wrong?

Comment: How are you invoking your code?

Comment: @HubertGrzeskowiak On the terminal, I use this line `scrapy crawl uae_free` to run the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why, but for some reason your XPath doesn't find the table body. I changed it to this and it seems to work now:

```
//table[@class="GridViewStyle"]//tr'
```